# When is a body coming back?

Tags: looper

I have a feeling this was answered in the movie but I can't find it anywhere.

How do the loopers know when a person is coming back in time that they need to kill? I saw him pick up a piece of paper (I think off the fridge or in the kitchen) but how does that get there to tell them to go to where/when the person will appear?

I'm sure I just missed it in the movie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I watched it again and it appears as if a slip of paper is put in his mailbox to tell him when the body will be coming back.

Answer (score 4):

I thought the crime boss set up the schedule of times and places in advance and sent that back to the past along with his lieutenant Jeff Daniels.
Any changes to the schedule can be sent along with the victims.